# How to calculate the cosine similarity of two string list by sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have two lists with string like that,

```
a_file = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b_file = ['b', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

I want to calculate the cosine similarity of these two list and I know how to realize it by,

```
# count word occurrences
a_vals = Counter(a_file)
b_vals = Counter(b_file)

# convert to word-vectors
words  = list(a_vals.keys() | b_vals.keys())
a_vect = [a_vals.get(word, 0) for word in words]       
b_vect = [b_vals.get(word, 0) for word in words]        

# find cosine
len_a  = sum(av*av for av in a_vect) ** 0.5             
len_b  = sum(bv*bv for bv in b_vect) ** 0.5             
dot    = sum(av*bv for av,bv in zip(a_vect, b_vect))   
cosine = dot / (len_a * len_b) 

print(cosine)
```

However, if I want to use `cosine_similarity`in sklearn, it shows the problem:`could not convert string to float: 'a'` How to correct it?

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

a_file = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b_file = ['b', 'x', 'y', 'z']
print(cosine_similarity(a_file, b_file))
```

Comment: How do you want to define cosine similarity on characters?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe first check [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html) to see if it calculates what you need. It seems it needs numbers, not strings/chars.

Comment: this works for me `cosine_similarity([a_vect], [b_vect])` . First: it needs word-vectors. Second: it needs two dimentional vectors - like in `DataFrame` with many rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it needs

- word-vectors,
- two dimentional data (list with many word-vectors)

```
print(cosine_similarity( [a_vect], [b_vect] ))
```

---

Full working code:

```
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

a_file = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b_file = ['b', 'x', 'y', 'z']

# count word occurrences
a_vals = Counter(a_file)
b_vals = Counter(b_file)

# convert to word-vectors
words  = list(a_vals.keys() | b_vals.keys())
a_vect = [a_vals.get(word, 0) for word in words]       
b_vect = [b_vals.get(word, 0) for word in words]        

# find cosine
len_a  = sum(av*av for av in a_vect) ** 0.5             
len_b  = sum(bv*bv for bv in b_vect) ** 0.5             
dot    = sum(av*bv for av,bv in zip(a_vect, b_vect))   
cosine = dot / (len_a * len_b) 

print(cosine)
print(cosine_similarity([a_vect], [b_vect]))
```

Result:

```
0.2886751345948129
[[0.28867513]]
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also use one list with all data (so second argument will be `None`)
and it will compare all pairs `(a,a)`, `(a,b)`, `(b,a)`, `(b,b)`.

```
print(cosine_similarity( [a_vect, b_vect] ))
```

Result:

```
[[1.         0.28867513]
 [0.28867513 1.        ]]
```

You can use longer list `[a,b,c, ...]` and it will check all possible pairs.

---

Documentation: [cosine_similarity](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html)